# Homebrew on Mac Os 10.10 or 10.11 is not working

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

After installed [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), when I run any `brew ***`, I keep getting this error:

```
Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew
```

My Env: Mac OS 10.10(Yosemite)

I checked the `brew.rb` source, it has:

```
if MACOS and MACOS_VERSION < 10.5
  abort <<-EOABORT.undent
    Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
    http://github.com/sceaga/homebrew/tree/tiger
  EOABORT
end
```

I have no idea why the Yosemite will trigger this version check.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Edit the `brew.rb` file to get this :

```
# 10.10 stands for Mac OS Yosemite
# 10.11 stands for Mac OS El Capitan
if MACOS and MACOS_VERSION < 10.5 and MACOS_VERSION != 10.1 and MACOS_VERSION != 10.11
  abort <<-EOABORT.undent
    Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
    http://github.com/sceaga/homebrew/tree/tiger
  EOABORT
end
```

It'll then install fine.

This is because `10.10` is the same than `10.1` which is below `10.5`

Comment: Where is brew.rb located?

Comment: @Tone the file is here: `/usr/local/Library/brew.rb`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas I did look there seems I was not set correctly and reinstalled homebrew.

Comment: I'm on El Capitan and didnt find `/usr/local/Library/brew.rb`. But found the same check under `/usr/local/bin/brew`

Comment: I was having this problem after Sierra update, using 10.12 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Above change did not work for me..
it gave the error
Error: Mac OS X `10.1' is invalid

I had to change the brew.rb to:

```
if MACOS_VERSION == 10.10
        MACOS_VERSION = 10.99
end
```

before

```
if MACOS and MACOS_VERSION < 10.5
```