# Django can't be found in a Heroku Python Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv

Update: Problem solved. See the answer in the answers section.

---

Today is the first day I'm working on Heroku with Python, and I have successfully worked through [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction) to set things up on my MacBook Pro. I also want to do some side Django project myself and that's where I ran into the problem where the virtual environment can't find Django, even though the tutorial is installing a simple Django app on the virtual environment.  Strangely, everything in the tutorial worked perfectly for me, including `heroku local` and `heroku open`.

On [this step](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies), I got into my virtualenv with `source virtualenvname/bin/activate` and then successfully completed `pip install -r requirements.txt`, which contains a line for "Django==1.9.2".

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.9.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

As you can see above, it seems like the Django is already there in my virtualenv.

But if I start a python console in my virtualenv with `python`, it can't find django!

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

What's going on?? I need to make sure I have Django before I can continue.

---

Updates from comments:

Running the commands from comments.

First from outside the virtualenv:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ pip freeze
altgraph==0.10.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
dj-database-url==0.4.0
Django==1.9.2
futures==3.0.5
gunicorn==19.4.5
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
psycopg2==2.6.1
py2app==0.7.3
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
...
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
python-swiftclient==3.0.0
pytz==2013.7
requests==2.9.1
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.4.1
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==15.0.2
whitenoise==2.0.6
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Inside the virtual env gives the same output above.

Comment: run `pip freeze`, can you see your installed packages?

Comment: Django wasn't actually installed in your virtual environment. It was installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. Verify you're running the right `pip` with `which pip`.

Comment: SvekarP and kichik, I have done `pip freeze` and `which pip` (see the update). What can I do now to have python recognize the  Django that I have on my computer?

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/769

Comment: SvekarP and kichlik. Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to cdunklau from irc #python. The solution was because my MacBook (OS X El Capitan)'s brew was too outdated for Django, that `brew doctor` said:

```
Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
http://github.com/sceaga/homebrew/tree/tiger
```

My Python was really old too, it had version 2.7.1.

So to fix it I had to

1. Update Homebrew: [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504139/4825465)
2. Update Python on my Homebrew: `brew install python`

Now my python is up to 2.7.12 and I can `import django` in a Python console. :)